# Download media from twitter direct messages

Tags: twitter

I want download pictures from twitter direct messages.

```
using (var cli = new WebClient())
{
     cli.DownloadFile(file.Address, file.Path);
}
```

where `file.Address` is uri of picture.

But instead of `.jpg` file I get html-page.

Thank you!

Comment: what is the `file.Address` you're seeing?

Comment: when I detect that direct message contains media, I store uri of media in `file.Address`

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it is because you miss some HTTP headers in your request to behave like a browser and not like a bot. You may also have to provide an `auth_token` cookie if the images are from a private conversation.

Here are the headers I use:

```
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0'
'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01'
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

You can have a look at a [tool](https://github.com/Mincka/DMArchiver) I have created to download my direct messages, with the ability to also download the uploaded images and GIFs (as MP4).

The images are downloaded in a separate folder with a reference in the filename to the tweet ID.